# Maven build failure related to licensing

Tags: java, maven, build, neo4j

I'm trying to build neo4j source code, after syncing up from Github, however the build is not proceeding further throwing up an error message while dealing with license.

Any thought why is this happening ? i tried skipping license (`-Dlicense.skip=true`) did not help me out...

Using maven to build:

```
$ mvn clean install -Dlicense.skip=true

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:licensing-maven-plugin:1.
7.5:check (list-all-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Generated file differs fr
om the existing file.
[ERROR] Generated: C:\Neo\build\neo4j\community\kernel\target\neo4j-kernel-1.9-S
NAPSHOT-NOTICE.txt
[ERROR] Existing: C:\Neo\build\neo4j\community\kernel\target\..\NOTICE.txt
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Comment: +1 for getting a licensing issue to cause the build to fail.

Comment: What about `mvn clean install -Dlicense.skip=true -DminimalBuild`? Are you building from the root pom?

Comment: $ mvn clean install -Dlicensing.skip will fix this problem, this avoids checking 3rd party license.

Comment: -Dlicense.skip=true with this option still get the error.